# Need to change menu item popup direction in wpf

Tags: wpf

I docked the menu control in the bottom of page, but it expands down. Can anyone help to expand it upwards. I need to expand towards top

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Menu Open direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378993/wpf-menu-open-direction)

Comment: I need not the menu items, But menu list in menu should go up from bottom. is there any idea?

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what you are asking then. I thought the question was about the submenu that expands when clicking one of the menu items. You might want to rephrase it a bit

Comment: Actually I cant add image here, due to low reputation. Sorry for the inconvenience. In my main window, I have a menu of height 200, which is vertically aligned. and menu list is shown from the top of menu. Here i need to change this starting position to bottom. Hope it is understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code in the menu

```
           <Menu.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

It is done

Answer (score 0):

```
<Menu>
   <MenuItem x:Name="menuitem"/>
</Menu>

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent ();

   menuitem.ApplyTemplate ();
   Popup pop = menuitem.Template.FindName ( "PART_Popup", menuitem ) as Popup;
   if ( pop != null )  pop.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
}
```